# Firestore how to query data from collection where document reference contains specific query path

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**How to query data from collection where document reference contain specific path?**

Here is my Firestore database, filed user is a document reference type, mapped document reference form other collection.

[image]

Here I need to get all data from **userinfo** collection where user document reference contains specific path (eg : *player/8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR/playerinfo* )

I have tried following query but seems not working:

```
Query query = mFirebaseFirestore.collection("userinfo").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("user", "player/8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR/playerinfo");
```

Code to get data from query:

```
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    //queried data here
                }
 });
```

No example available on document to query Firestore with document reference type.

Please help me to query list of document from collection where document reference having specific path.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo no, i need exact solution for my need

Answer (score 1):

You don't find any examples in the official documentation of Firestore because unfortunately, there is no `contains()` method which can help you verify if a String is apart of a reference, which is a property of a document.

However, if you want to get all document that exist under `playerinfo` collection, then just use a `get()` call. Don't use `addSnapshotListener()` unless you need to get data in real-time.

There is a solution in which you need to transform your `user` property to be of type String and use a query that look like this:

```
Query query = = mFirebaseFirestore.collection("userinfo").whereEqualTo("user", "player/8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR/playerinfo");
```

But rememeber, this will work only if the property `user` holds a value of type String which is equal to:

```
player/8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR/playerinfo`
```

and **not**:

```
player/8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR/playerinfo/qY0D7Vef...
                                       ^      ^
```

There is one more in way in which you can solve this. Query the entire collection, get all the values of `user` property and add them to a `List` by converting them from `Reference` to String. In the end, just iterate over the list and use `contains()` method on each element.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to get the document by its location in the database:

```
mFirebaseFirestore.collection("userinfo").document("8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR").get()
```

No need for a query if you know the specific document to fetch.

Comment: your answer is not exact as i want, at this point i am not getting only one document, i need to get all document list that belongs to particular collection (note: that collection inside particular document reference path )

Comment: eg: _player/8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR/playerinfo_                                     **playerinfo** is a collection that under particular document (_8SLuNWrI09UIuUfNe7ZR_). here i need to get all document that under playerinfo collection